# Question about 1098-T Tax form

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I graduated college in May of 2015. I just received my 1098-T form for the 2015 year, which includes my spring semester. In box 2, "Amounts billed for qualified tuition and related expenses", it is blank which doesn't make sense to me. In box 5, "Scholarships or grants", it shows $4,210.00, which seems correct based on the 2014 1098-T form I received. While my scholarships and grants have usually covered my tuition (I'm lucky), I did have to pay $253.50 in early January 2015 for tuition. I don't understand why Box 2 is blank. Can someone explain what I'm missing, and will this affect my tax return greatly?

Comment: Does Box 1 (payments received) show the $253 payment that you made?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Are you sure that the $253 you paid was to cover tuition and not something like "student fees" or some other kind of fee? My wife has paid many fees like this, even though her tuition is covered by grants.